# How did Cornelius Fudge discover that Sirius was in fact innocent?

Tags: harry-potter, sirius-black

In Chapter one of *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Cornelius visits "The Other Minister" and is asked if the visit has anything to do with this "Serious Black" man, and Fudge states that no, it turned out that he was actually innocent.

> ‘Is Serious Black with – er – He Who Must Not Be Named?’
>
> ‘Black? Black?’ said Fudge distractedly, turning his bowler rapidly in his fingers.  ‘Sirius Black, you mean? Merlin's beard, no. Black's dead. Turns out we were – er – mistaken about Black. He was innocent after all. And he wasn't in league with He Who Must Not Be Named either. […]’
>
> – *The Half-Blood Prince* Chapter 1: The Other Minister

### How did he come to that realization and conclusion?

Comment: This is a nice question and I have edited in the quote I believe you are talking about. However, it appears this question has been asked before.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Thank you for the edit. Yes, I suppose it does. Oh well. :)